# Static method in abstract class to return IEnumerable<DerivedType>

Tags: c#, generics

Is there a way of putting a static method in an abstract class that can return the derived type?

Does a static method even know what type it is even being called from in C#?

For example, a base class could be

```
public abstract class MyBase
{
    public static IEnumerable<TDerivedType> LoadAll()
    {
        //functionality here
    }
}
```

Then if `MyDerivedType` inherits `MyBase`, I'd like to be able to call `MyDerivedType.LoadAll()`

Nothing too important - I'm currently using a generic static method and calling `MyBase.LoadAll<MyDerivedType>()`, which works fine but it doesn't look quite as 'pretty' as this would be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Static members aren't inherited, so the static method has to be told in some way what the derived type is. Your solution is one way. Another is the following:

```
public abstract class MyBase<T> where T : MyBase<T> {
    public static IEnumerable<T> LoadAll() { }
}
```

Then:

```
class Derived : MyBase<Derived> { }

var all = MyBase<Derived>.LoadAll();
```

That said, I think there is something wrong with your model. `MyBase` represents something in your domain (of which they are more specific derived types) AND it knows how to load all of those objects? That's two responsibilities, and that ain't cool yo.

Comment: It should be … `where T : MyBase<T>`. Good answer though I disagree that this is necessarily a bad model. Having a base class contain static convenience methods (especially builder methods) is common (see e.g. `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`) and makes sense.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: I'd argue those static builder methods on `Expression` should live in another class. :-|

Comment: Good solution. Regarding your last part of the answer - the base object knows how to create its derived types through calling the constructor. I should've put in the question; that method signature is `public static IEnumerable<TDerivedType> LoadAll() where TDerivedType : MyBase, new()`

Comment: @Connell Watkins: That doesn't solve the problem. It just enables it to persist.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with an object knowing how to call its own constructor. After constructing it calls a `Load` method which is passed some arguments, which is also implemented in `MyBase`.

Comment: +1 for a useful answer.  -1 for the commentary on the model.  If all things that derive from MyBase are stored in the same manner, it's perfectly reasonable for them all to be loaded in the same manner.  The subclass can point to the specific location, but the method is the same regardless.

Answer (score 2):

No, there currently isn't a way to do this. I'd possibly use a factory in this case

```
var all = MyClassFactory.LoadAll<MyDerivedType>();
```

Answer (score 1):

An abstract class can never be instantiated(that's the whole point) so any static methods would have to be implemented in each child class.

From [an MSDN Thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharplanguage/thread/19a968ce-7d8b-4cf9-b0f0-292464f1e708)

> Static methods can be defined in an abstract class. However, you cannot force a derived class to implement a static method. If you think about it, such a method would be useless. Static methods are invoked using type names, not instance variables. If I call MyBaseClass.MyMethod, then MyBaseClass.MyMethod will always be invoked. How would it do you any good to force MyChildClass, which inherits from MyBaseClass, to also a implement a static MyMethod?

(Note: edited implemented to instantiated in the first sentence.)

Comment: I don't agree with your first sentence. Classes that are `abstract` can not be __instantiated__, and they can provide implementations for methods.

Comment: Good quote. I'm using inheritance here, not for substitution reasons but simply to stop myself from writing the same code over and over for each class. In this case I do want to be able to call MyChildClass.MyMethod, which calls MyBaseClass.MyMethod<MyChildClass>.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the way you are doing this. In fact most of MS generic extension methods are designed like this.

As for:

"Does a static method even know what type it is even being called from in C#?"

Its not a question of the static method knowing, its a question of the compiler knowing. When the code is scanned by the compiler this is when all the types are consolidated. At this point it can work out what code calls what functions and what types need to be returned. This is also the reason that a `var` type cannot be returned from a function.